How to compare two tab-separated files and mark 'Fail' if col6 of file1 matches col2 of file2, else 'Pass'?
I want to compare two tab-separated files (with headers) and check whether column 6 of the first file (peptide.tsv) matches exactly with column 2 of the second file (proteome.tsv). If there is an exact match, print Fail, otherwise print Pass. Also col6 may not be unique. There can be identical sequences with different locus.
==\> test_peptide.tsv \<==
FusionID        Peptide HLA_Allele      EL-score        EL_Rank AA_seq_full
TUFT1--PBXIP1|chr1:151540426:+|chr1:154951535:-|FRAMESHIFT      GSDGCWGLY       HLA-A01:01      0.79990000000000006     0.1002  MNGTRNWCTLVDVHPEDQAAGRSSRLKALSLAAF*QRRLRSRAPWKVMFVVWSLLAQETQ*SRETCRRPP
TUFT1--PBXIP1|chr1:151540426:+|chr1:154948366:-|FRAMESHIFT      GSDGCWGLY       HLA-A01:01      0.79990000000000006     0.1002  MNOVEL*PEPTIDE

==\> test_proteome.tsv \<==
Name    AA_seq
sp|A0A0G2JMI3|HV692_HUMAN Immunoglobulin heavy variable 1-69-2 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=IGHV1-69-2 PE=1 SV=2  MDCTWRILLLVAAATGTHAEVQLVQSGAEVKKPGATVKISCKVSGYTFTDYYMHWVQQAPGKGLEWMGLVDPEDGETIYAEKFQGRVTITADTSTDTAYMELSSLRSEDTAVYYCA
rp|A0A0G2JMI3|HV692_HUMAN Immunoglobulin heavy variable 1-69-2 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=IGHV1-69-2 PE=1 SV=6  MNGTRNWCTLVDVHPEDQAAGRSSRLKALSLAAF*QRRLRSRAPWKVMFVVWSLLAQETQ*SRETCRRPPT

What I am getting:
FusionIDPass    Peptide HLA_Allele      EL-score        EL_Rank AA_seq_full
TUFT1--PBXIP1|chr1:151540426:+|chr1:154951535:-|FRAMESHIFT      GSDGCWGLY       HLA-A01:01      0.79990000000000006     0.1002  MNGTRNWCTLVDVHPEDQAAGRSSRLKALSLAAF*QRRPassAPWKVMFVVWSLLAQETQ*SRETCRRPP
TUFT1--PPass1|chr1:151540426:+|chr1:154948366:-|FRAMESHIFT      GSDGCWGLY       HLA-A01:01      0.79990000000000006     0.1002  MNOVEL*PEPTIDE

Tried these
awk -F\\t 'NR==FNR {a\[$2\];next} {print $0 FS (($6) in a?"Fail":"Pass")}' test_proteome.tsv test_peptide.tsv

awk 'NR==FNR {proteome\[$2\]; next} {status = ($6 in proteome ? "Fail" : "Pass"); print $0 "\\t" status}' test_proteome.tsv test_peptide.tsv

expected_output.tsv
FusionID        Peptide HLA_Allele      EL-score        EL_Rank AA_seq_full
TUFT1--PBXIP1|chr1:151540426:+|chr1:154951535:-|FRAMESHIFT      GSDGCWGLY       HLA-A01:01      0.79990000000000006     0.1002  MNGTRNWCTLVDVHPEDQAAGRSSRLKALSLAAF*QRRLRSRAPWKVMFVVWSLLAQETQ*SRETCRRPP Fail
TUFT1--PBXIP1|chr1:151540426:+|chr1:154948366:-|FRAMESHIFT      GSDGCWGLY       HLA-A01:01      0.79990000000000006     0.1002  MNOVEL\*PEPTIDE Pass


please update the question with the exact code you've tried; the two awk scripts you've provided only generate syntax errors

please verify the input data; right now there are no exact matches; the two strings that start with MNGTRN... end with different strings: SRETCRRPP vs SRETCRRPPT (note the 1st is missing the trailing T); do you we need to look for an exact match or a match of a substring?

An example using a bash script in a didactic way, not compressed in a one liner awk command
#!/bin/bash

# Input files
file1="test_peptide.tsv"
file2="test_proteome.tsv"

# Output file
output_file="output.tsv"

# Column numbers to compare
column1=6
column2=2

#write the headers to the output file
printf '%s\tResult\n' "$(head -n 1 $file1)" > $output_file

#for row 2 to the number of lines in the file1
for i in $(seq 2 "$(cat $file1 | wc -l)")
do
    if [ "$(awk -F '\t' -v i="$i" -v col1="$column1" 'NR==i {print $col1}' $file1)" \
    == "$(awk -F '\t' -v i="$i" -v col2="$column2" 'NR==i {print $col2}' $file2)" ]
    then
        printf '%s\tFail\n' "$(awk -v i="$i" 'NR==i {print $0}' $file1)" >> $output_file
    else
        printf '%s\tPass\n' "$(awk -v i="$i" 'NR==i {print $0}' $file1)" >> $output_file
    fi
done


using a bash loop to process text files one-line-at-a-time is going to be (relatively) slow and inefficient; spawning 4 subshells for each pass through the loop will add more overhead/time; opening/writing-to/closing the output file on each pass through the loop will add more overhead/time

the whole -v i=$i / NR==i logic assumes the two files are (basically) joined by line number; this isn't the case as demonstrated in OP's example data where the MNGTRN ... RRPP string is in line #2 of test_peptide.tsv and line #3 of test_proteome.tsv

@shafaque running this code against the sample data you've provided does not generate the desired result (ie, it generates Pass on the end of both data lines); this is due to this code only matching line #x from both files; if this code really does generate the desired results then please update the question with a valid set of input data and confirmation that we're supposed to be matching based on column_6 vs column_2 and matching line numbers

the echo -e $(awk ... ) \t... construct requires a useless echo and unnecessary subshell when a simple awk call would suffice; then again, performing 4x separate awk calls for each pass through the loop is excessive, especially when you could perform the looping within a single awk script

@markp-fuso I agree it's inefficient so I warned didactic, your command works correctly (also compares in a row n to row n basis), maybe just lacks  ``>output.tsv`  at the end to write the result to output.tsv file, I don't know what level of expertise the OP has on shell command/scripting. A much better solution would be to load that data into a database (strongly typed) and process it there.

also compares in a row n to row n basis - no it does not; FNR==NR stores values from first file in array a[]; FNR==1 addresses header row of second file; rest of script does a lookup of the current field #6 (of second file) against the indices of array a[] via ($6) in a

correction .. 3x subshells and 3x awk calls per pass through the loop

the awk scripts need to be updated to designate FS='\t' otherwise the processing of test_proteome.tsv will fail since the first column contains embedded white space (ie, the values in the column 2 of test_proteome.tsv will be AA_seq, Immunoglobulin and Immunoglobulin).

@markp-fuso I see and tested, your command performs a sort of cross product comparison, then seems that OP wanted a n to n as I interpreted, but unclear in the question text. There is no a clear relation between the fields other than row order.

if OP wants comparisons between liked numbered lines then there are no matches in OP's sample data; as for what's being compared ... in database terms, column #6 of test_peptide.tsv is a FK to the reference table test_proteome.tsv with column #2 being its PK/index; again, in database terms, there is no relationship of row (line) numbers between the two tables (files)

@EdMorton ok, thanks, I'll try to improve that answer later

Counting lines or enumerating line numbers so I can loop over them - why is this an anti-pattern?

This smells like an A.I. generated answer. Even a newbie shell script writer will not be able to write this complex shell/awk script alone. (In-my-opinion)

Since OP has posted the (incorrect) output generated by their code I'm going to assume the awk scripts they've posted are not their real code otherwise the escaped brackets would be generating syntax errors, g:
$ awk -F\\t 'NR==FNR {a\[$2\];next} {print $0 FS (($6) in a?"Fail":"Pass")}' test_proteome.tsv test_peptide.tsv
awk: cmd. line:1: NR==FNR {a\[$2\];next} {print $0 FS (($6) in a?"Fail":"Pass")}
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ backslash not last character on line
awk: cmd. line:1: NR==FNR {a\[$2\];next} {print $0 FS (($6) in a?"Fail":"Pass")}
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error

Also, to designate a tab as the field delimiter we need to quote the \t.
Until OP updates the question with the actual code I'm going to assume we're starting with the following:
awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR {a[$2];next} {print $0 FS (($6) in a?"Fail":"Pass")}' test_proteome.tsv test_peptide.tsv

awk 'NR==FNR {proteome[$2]; next} {status = ($6 in proteome ? "Fail" : "Pass"); print $0 "\t" status}' test_proteome.tsv test_peptide.tsv

The second script will fail to generate the desired results because awk will use the default field separator of white space (ie, all spaces and tabs will be processed as field separators).  This means the values in the column 2 of test_proteome.tsv are AA_seq, Immunoglobulin and Immunoglobulin.
If we update the second script to awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR ...' we find that both scripts now generate:
FusionID    Peptide HLA_Allele  EL-score    EL_Rank AA_seq_full Pass
TUFT1--PBXIP1|chr1:151540426:+|chr1:154951535:-|FRAMESHIFT  GSDGCWGLY   HLA-A01:01  0.79990000000000006 0.1002  MNGTRNWCTLVDVHPEDQAAGRSSRLKALSLAAF*QRRLRSRAPWKVMFVVWSLLAQETQ*SRETCRRPP  Pass
TUFT1--PBXIP1|chr1:151540426:+|chr1:154948366:-|FRAMESHIFT  GSDGCWGLY   HLA-A01:01  0.79990000000000006 0.1002  MNOVEL*PEPTIDE  Pass

A couple issues:

header line has the string Pass appended on the end (OP hasn't coded anything to handle the header so the ternary operation applies here, too)
the first data line ends with Pass instead of Fail

Looking at the data we see there are no matches in the given input data; of particular interest are the strings that start with MNGTRN:
test_proteome.tsv : MNGTRN ... RRPPT
test_peptide.tsv  : MNGTRN ... RRPP

Notice one has a trailing T while the other is missing the trailing T.  Since OP has stated we are looking for an exact match, and we have no exact matches, this associated line is appended with Pass.
Since OP's expected output does not display the trailing T I'm going to assume this was a typo.  I've removed the trailing T from my copy of test_proteome.tsv.
At this point both of OP's scripts generate the desired output ... except for that Pass in the header line:
FusionID    Peptide HLA_Allele  EL-score    EL_Rank AA_seq_full Pass
TUFT1--PBXIP1|chr1:151540426:+|chr1:154951535:-|FRAMESHIFT  GSDGCWGLY   HLA-A01:01  0.79990000000000006 0.1002  MNGTRNWCTLVDVHPEDQAAGRSSRLKALSLAAF*QRRLRSRAPWKVMFVVWSLLAQETQ*SRETCRRPP  Fail
TUFT1--PBXIP1|chr1:151540426:+|chr1:154948366:-|FRAMESHIFT  GSDGCWGLY   HLA-A01:01  0.79990000000000006 0.1002  MNOVEL*PEPTIDE  Pass

Modifying OP's 1st script to handle the header line:
########
# do not add to the header line:

$ awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR {a[$2];next} FNR==1 {print $0;next} {print $0 FS (($6) in a?"Fail":"Pass")}' test_proteome.tsv test_peptide.tsv
FusionID    Peptide HLA_Allele  EL-score    EL_Rank AA_seq_full
TUFT1--PBXIP1|chr1:151540426:+|chr1:154951535:-|FRAMESHIFT  GSDGCWGLY   HLA-A01:01  0.79990000000000006 0.1002  MNGTRNWCTLVDVHPEDQAAGRSSRLKALSLAAF*QRRLRSRAPWKVMFVVWSLLAQETQ*SRETCRRPP  Fail
TUFT1--PBXIP1|chr1:151540426:+|chr1:154948366:-|FRAMESHIFT  GSDGCWGLY   HLA-A01:01  0.79990000000000006 0.1002  MNOVEL*PEPTIDE  Pass


########
# add 'Result' on end of header line:

$ awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR {a[$2];next} FNR==1 {print $0 FS "Result";next} {print $0 FS (($6) in a?"Fail":"Pass")}' test_proteome.tsv test_peptide.tsv
FusionID    Peptide HLA_Allele  EL-score    EL_Rank AA_seq_full Result
TUFT1--PBXIP1|chr1:151540426:+|chr1:154951535:-|FRAMESHIFT  GSDGCWGLY   HLA-A01:01  0.79990000000000006 0.1002  MNGTRNWCTLVDVHPEDQAAGRSSRLKALSLAAF*QRRLRSRAPWKVMFVVWSLLAQETQ*SRETCRRPPT Fail
TUFT1--PBXIP1|chr1:151540426:+|chr1:154948366:-|FRAMESHIFT  GSDGCWGLY   HLA-A01:01  0.79990000000000006 0.1002  MNOVEL*PEPTIDE  Pass

NOTE: I'm assuming the next-to-last field of the last line in OP's expected output is a typo and the asterisk is not supposed to be escaped, ie, MNOVEL\*PEPTIDE should be MNOVEL*PEPTIDE

I am really sorry for the typos. I suspect there are some hidden characters in the files too. Thanks for the lead and clarification of code.

@shafaque please update the question to fix the typos so in the future when others come across your question they don't have to deal with typos and the associated confusion; it (fixing the typos) would also allow me to reduce the size of my answer by only having to focus on the coding issues

Regarding "to designate a tab as the field delimiter we need to quote the \t" - I agree we should use -F'\t' but what the OP has, -F\\t would actually work as the double backslashes without quotes would do the same as quotes regarding awk seeing a single backslash (i.e. protect one of the backslashes from the shell). Also some versions of awk take a literal t on it's own as meaning tab-separated so even -Ft can mean 'tab-separated' to some awks, e.g. try printf 'a\tb\n' | awk --traditional -Ft '{print $1}' with GNU awk and you'll see it outputs a.

@EdMorton hmmm, hadn't thought about that; I was focused on OP's invalid escapes for the brackets as well as print $0 "\\t" status (2nd awk script) and (blindly) assumed OP was being overzealous with the escape re: -F\\t; leaving -F\\t would then lead to having to explain why that's ok but print $0 "\\t" status is not ok; as for -Ft ... just when I thought I was getting the hang of awking ... yuck

There's always one more dark corner .... :-).
